# How to add Body in Url in Volley request in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, android-volley, kotlin-android-extensions, rx-kotlin

Here is my Code that for Volley Request:-

```
    val searchRequest = object : JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
            Response.Listener { response ->

                val result = response.toString()


            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                Log.d("ERROR",error.toString())
            })
    {
        override fun getBody(): ByteArray {

           //   TODO add Body, Header section works  //////////

            return super.getBody()
        }

        override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
            return "application/json"
        }


        override fun getHeaders() : Map<String,String> {
            val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            params["Search-String"] = songName
            params["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${accessTx.text}"
            return params
        }
    }
    AppController.instance!!.addToRequestQueue(searchRequest)
```

I want to add this information in the body section

video_id =  "BDJIAH" , 
audio_quality = "256"

here is the sample to add above information in the below segment.

{
"video_id":"ABCDE",
 "audio_quality":"256"
}

Basically, I am facing problem in ByteArray section. That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function i created to send a call to server and this is how you will add body in your call.

```
    fun sendcall() {
            //RequestQueue initialized
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

           //String Request initialized
            mStringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, Response.Listener { response ->
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Logged In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.i("This is the error", "Error :" + error.toString())
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please make sure you enter correct password and username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }) {
                override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                    return "application/json"
                }

                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                    val params2 = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params2.put("Login","your credentials" )
                    params2.put("Password", "your credentials")
                    return JSONObject(params2).toString().toByteArray()
                }

            }
            mRequestQueue!!.add(mStringRequest!!)
        }
```

Comment: Since I'm new to Kotlin I was getting an error with the override functions. Make sure you have the "object :" syntax before the StringRequest constructor. See doc here for further explanation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Comment: This worked with modifications:  I got errors with the return statement, which I changed to `return JSONObject(params2 as Map<*, *>).toString().toByteArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Volley post request in kotlin with params

```
private fun loginUser() {
    val username: String = etName.getText().toString().trim()
    val password: String = etPass.getText().toString().trim()
    val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest( Method.POST, LOGINURL,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            try {
                val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
                //Parse your api responce here
                /*val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)*/
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }) {
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            //Change with your post params
            params["username"] = username
            params["password"] = password
            return params
        }
    }
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
}
```