# Android: HTTP request with Volley fails to call with parameters

Tags: android, json, http, flask, android-volley

I deployed a NLP model as an API with Flask. Now I want to call the API from my simple Android app to process some text and to return a prediction, however when the Android App performs the HTTP request using Volley it does not add the parameters in the URL for some reason. Here is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // button
        val showButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.showInput)

        // text
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)

        // Setting On Click Listener
        showButton.setOnClickListener {

            // user input
            val text = editText.text

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "http://192.168.100.12:5000/"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
            val request = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                Response.Listener {
                        response ->
                    editText.setText(response.toString())
            },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.i("error ", error.toString())
                editText.setText("Volley error: $it ")
            }) {

                override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                    return "application/json"
                }

                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                    val params = HashMap<String,String>()
                    params.put("text", text.toString())
                    return params.toString().toByteArray()
                }

            }

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(request)
            // Showing the response
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

In essence, I am expecting the URL to be "http://192.168.100.12:5000/?text=<insert_text_here>", but the actual URL that the app calls is just "http://192.168.100.12:5000" without the parameters.
I know this because my Flask app returns this error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`
The error response code is 500.

I tested the Flask API with both the browser and Postman and it is working fine, but just in case I will leave the code here:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request,jsonify
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import traceback
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        tweet = request.args.get('text')
        model = open('model.pkl','rb')
        model = joblib.load(model)
        prediction = model.predict([tweet])
        
        if prediction == [0]:
            return 'This tweet does not violate our Community Guidelines'
        else:
            return 'This tweet violates out Community Guidelines for hate speech'
    except:
        return traceback.format_exc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '192.168.100.12',debug=True)
```

So far I also have tried the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219187/how-to-add-body-in-url-in-volley-request-in-kotlin) post as well as using the GET method with `getParams()` function instead of `getBody()` as shown below, but none of them worked.

```
  @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
                    val params: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                    params["text"] = text.toString()
                    return params
                }
```

Can you please help me solve this issue? I would be very grateful.